# guardar vista de Consulta en access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hola estoy creando una aplicacion vb.net con una base de dato access, como el programa lo distribuyo y la base de datos se instala en la maquina destino, debo manipular la base de en caso de alguna modificacion en las tablas mediante codigo, la manipulacion de las tablas va al pelo, la cosa se me ha complicado porque no he podido crear vistas en access, he leido por alli que no las soporta, en fin, sé que con el asistente puedo crear una consulta y access la guarda automaticamente como si fuera una tabla mas, ademas te deja ver el codigo sql de dicha consulta, el problemas es que no puedo crear las vistas por codigo o como hacer que access les coloque un nombre como lo hace con el asistente
he intentado con lo siguiente y me dice error al crear tabla :

CREATE VIEW  VENANEM (nrocomp, descripcion, fecomp, cant, und, prec, mes)  AS SELECT compras.nrocomp, consumibles.descripcion, compras.feccomp, compras.cant, compras.und, compras.precio, MonthName(Month([feccomp])) AS mes
FROM consumibles INNER JOIN compras ON (compras.producto = consumibles.descripcion) AND (consumibles.descripcion = compras.producto) AND (consumibles.descripcion = compras.producto);

la consulta por si sola trabaja bien, lo que quiero es guardarla con un nombre.

Comment: Deberías poder crearte una QueryDef accediendo por DAO a tu base en Access. Lee [Método Database.CreateQueryDef (DAO)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao) a ver si te puede servir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás intentado crear la Query desde SQl, pero creo que debes poder hacerlo instanciando desde VB.Net el objeto QueryDef
Fíjate en el ejemplo, y mira como está tratando la Query.
Parece que se pueden crear consultas temporales, que no llevan nombre y con nombre.
Al indicar el nombre la convierte en definitiva y debería guardarla Access desde vb.net.

El método CreateQueryDef con el parámetro adecuado parece la clave. y tambien el código SQL en sí mismo, ya que tendrás que adaptarlo con un SELECT o UPDATE o lo que quieras obtener, ya que el CREATE VIEW usando este ejemplo no te va a funcionar.

> Para crear un nuevo objeto QueryDef, utilice el método CreateQueryDef.
> En un área de trabajo de Microsoft Access, si coloca una cadena para
> el argumento name o establece explícitamente la propiedad Name del
> nuevo objeto QueryDef en una cadena que no sea de longitud cero,
> creará un QueryDef permanente que se anexará automáticamente a la
> colección QueryDefs y se guardará en el disco. Suministrar una cadena
> de longitud cero como argumento name o establecer explícitamente la
> propiedad Name en una cadena de longitud cero generará un objeto
> QueryDef temporal.

```
Sub CreateQueryDefX() 
 
   Dim dbsNorthwind As Database 
   Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef 
   Dim qdfNew As QueryDef 
 
   Set dbsNorthwind = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb") 
 
   With dbsNorthwind 
      ' Create temporary QueryDef. 
      Set qdfTemp = .CreateQueryDef("", _ 
         "SELECT * FROM Employees") 
      ' Open Recordset and print report. 
      GetrstTemp qdfTemp 
      ' Create permanent QueryDef. 
      Set qdfNew = .CreateQueryDef("NewQueryDef", _ 
         "SELECT * FROM Categories") 
      ' Open Recordset and print report. 
      GetrstTemp qdfNew 
      ' Delete new QueryDef because this is a demonstration. 
      .QueryDefs.Delete qdfNew.Name 
      .Close 
   End With 
 
End Sub
```